# DataTables - Update column headers and then re-draw

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to be able to update the column header via jquery for a datatable.  The table will be empty (apart from the header), and the column titles will change based on used input.  I'm using datatables 1.10.9.

Create the datatable.

```
    $('#tbl1').dataTable({
          "autoWidth":false
        , "info":false
        , "JQueryUI":true
        , "ordering":true
        , "paging":false
        , "scrollY":"470px"
        , "scrollX":"1485px"
        , "scrollCollapse":true
        , "columnDefs": [
                    { className: "LeftNoWrap", "targets": [ 0,1 ] }
                ,   { className: "CenterNoWrap", "targets": [ 2,3 ] }
                ,   { className: "RightNoWrap", "targets": [ 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 ] }
            ]
    });
```

Create local variable.

```
    var dTable = $('#tbl1').DataTable();
```

Update a column title.

```
    $(dTable.column(1).header()).text('My title');
```

Load the data.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
        .....
    }
    dTable.draw();
```

However, the columns now don't line up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion the "correct" way to change header titles is

```js
dTable.columns(1).header().to$().text('My title)
```

> However, the columns now don't line up.

Hard to really make a proof of concept since we dont have an example demonstrating the problem. However, I think you just need to readjust the columns *after* you have inserted new data :

```js
dTable.columns.adjust().draw();
```

a small demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v8dkx0uz/**

Comment: That's great.  Not if is the problem was also linked to the datatable being within a closed accordion section.  So, in effect , it was hidden.  I moved the fill/redraw of the datatable to after the 'detail' accordion section was expanded.  Anyway, it's working great. Thanks.